# Dynamically find the right amount of timesteps for an LSTM RNN predicting timeseries

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm fairly new to the world of NNs so it could be that my question is extremely stupid, so sorry in advance:

I'm working on a predictive autoscaler, trying to predict the workload of different, unknown, applications using only historic workload data about this application.

One of my predictors is a LSTM RNN. To make the RNN predict the values in question, I have to define the timestep - that is the amount of Lags I feed in to the RNN to predict the future value (I hope I used the right terms here). Alot of tutorials and literature seems to set the timestep to a value that seems pretty random to me. My Question can be divided in two subquestions:

**1. Given I don't know the Timeseries during implementation: Is there any way to compute this value other than trying different values and comparing the confidence of the prediction?**

**2. How does the Value influence the assumptions the RNN learns about that time series?**

I sadly lack of any intuition on what this value influences. To make an example of my confusion:

Given I have a Time Series with a yearly seasonality, but I decide that I will only feed in the data of a week to make the next prediction: Is the Network able to learn this yearly seasonality? Part of me says no because it can't learn that the partial correlation between the timestamp in question and the lag 365 days ago is very high, because it does not have that data, right? Or does it because it has seen the data from a year ago while training and learned that fairly similar pattern and simply applies it now (which is more likely to be right I guess)?

Is my assumption right, that taking too many timestamps into the equation overfits the network?

Can you please help me get a vague understanding of what this parameter influences in the great scheme of things and what properties of a time series should influence my choice of that value?

Thank you so much and stay healthy :)